# How many original LEGO wooden ducks are left?

Tags: history, vintage, wooden-toys

I've been trying to learn about the [Wooden Pull-Along Duck with Long Bill](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=pullduck)

[image]

The only one I can see is owned by the LEGO Group themselves and is kept in the LEGO House.
Many were made in the 1930s and there should be a few still around, but I can't find any.
Is there any public collection which has one? Or an auction in which one was sold?

Comment: The only one I have ever seen was for sale in a car-booth sale in Bad Bramstedt (just north of Hamburg in Germany) in summer 2003. If I had known at the time what it was, I would have offered a lot more for it than the 1 EURO it was priced at....

Comment: @Tonny that's nearly as painful as doing the math on how much something cost me in Bitcoin when I bought it in 2013.

Comment: @tonny that's quite the miss! Although, the fact that it can crop up like that makes it all the stranger that it is so impossible to find them.

Comment: The problem is that whoever knows what they have will not part from it (at least presumably not on Bricklink), and those who don't know that their old wooden duck toy is actually an invaluable LEGO relic - well, they won't try to sell it or learn more about it.

Comment: @zovits Exactly that. People who know what it is will cash in or keep it as an investment. And those that don't know won't see any value and would sell it for peanuts or just throw/give it away. Finding one for sale cheaply... More chance to win the lottery than it ever happening to me a 2nd time.

Comment: Have you contacted Lego customer service? They are usually quite helpful.

Comment: @JenserCube I have, they didn't know of any Lego duck except the one in the Lego House

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question in your bounty edit ("*I'm looking for any public case of an original wooden duck being owned or sold*"):

[Here is a forum entry](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/122144-wanted-lego-wooden-duck/&tab=comments#comment-2498797) by someone in the USA who managed to buy one in 2016 from Denmark for 100$

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srpBTpS0cIA) is a review of the wooden duck, with the story of how it was acquired: "running a price of several thousand dollars".